# Rewrite rules with subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess

I need a way to get accessible all images in the folder:

```
sub1.example.com/images/
```

through URLs with a different subdomain ( sub2 ):

```
sub2.example.com/images/
```

For instance, the images **sub1.example.com/images/hello.jpg** is accessible ( only, if possible ) through **sub2.example.com/images/hello.jpg**

I just tryed this rule but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.example.com/images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1.example.com/images/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: sounds like you just need to add a ServerAlias in your apache config

Comment: So I can't do this with only htaccess ?

Comment: It depends what you have already, and exactly what you're trying to do.  Are both sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com serving files from the correct folder already?  Your server won't perform a rewrite for sub2 if it doesn't think it's hosting sub2.

Comment: yes, both subdomains serving files from the correct folder

Comment: Is your hosting shared ? do they have cPanel ? if you setup an addon domain to the same root of your domain it should work as u describe.

Comment: Yes is shared but I can't setup an addon domain to the same root :(

Comment: It will only be possible if you can enable mod_proxy on Apache server of `sub2.example.com`.

Comment: I have not this permission, I can only edit htaccess

Comment: Then point both subdomains to the same folder not in the root. `sub1` and `sub2` to folder `/home/your_account/public_html/subdomains` and move your images there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code rather :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub1.example.com/images/$1 [L,NC]
```